# Requests library & Pip Ntlm Proxy settings issues. - Python

Tags: git, proxy, pip, python-requests, ntlm

## Issue

I can't get the python requests library, easy_install, or pip to work behind the corporate proxy. I can, however, get git to work.

---

### How I got git working

I set the git proxy settings

> git config --global http.proxy http ://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080

- The corporate proxy server I work behind requires a user name and password and is indeed in the format

http: //username:passsword@ipaddress:port

- I did not have to set the http**s**.proxy

  ---

## Things I have tried

(None of it has worked)

#### Environment Variables -  Pip and Requests library

*Method 1*

> $ export HTTP_PROXY="http://username:passsword@ipaddress:port"
>
> $ export HTTPS_PROXY="http://username:passsword@ipaddress:port"

*Method 2*

> SET HTTP_PROXY="http://username:passsword@ipaddress:port"
>
> SET HTTPS_PROXy="HTTPS_PROXY="http://username:passsword@ipaddress:port"

- I have tried both restarting after setting the proxy variables, and trying them right after setting them
- Checking the variables with the 'SET' command shows that both are set correctly

---

#### Using Proxy Argument - Requests library

*Creating a dictionary with the proxy information and passing it to requests.get()*

> proxies = {
>    'http': 'http: //username:passsword@ipaddress:port',
>    'https': 'http: //username:passsword@ipaddress:port'}
>
> requests.get('http: //example.org', proxies=proxies)

---

#### Using Proxy Argument -  pip

> pip install library_name -–proxy=http: //username:passsword@ipaddress:port
>
> pip install library_name -–proxy=username:passsword@ipaddress:port

---

#### Results - Requests library

*Response*

> Response [407]

*Reason*

> 'Proxy Authorization Required'

*Header Information*

> {'Proxy-Authenticate': 'NTLM', 'Date': 'Fri, 05 May 2017 21:49:06 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset="UTF-8"', 'Content-Length': '4228', 'Accept-Ranges': 'none', 'Proxy-Connection': 'keep-alive'}

---

#### Results -  Pip

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
>   tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connectio
>   n failed: 407 Proxy Authorization Required',))'
>
> ---

*Note: In regards to this post, I have included a space in all my authentication 'links' between "http" and "://" because stackoverflow won't let me publish this with so many 'links'.*

(I set up a new Stackoverflow account as my old account was a login via facebook thing and I can't access it from work)

Comment: I know this is not a very constructive reply (that's why it's just a comment), but if your workplace makes your life harder by intercepting all traffic and blocking certain sites, then I would consider to start looking for a more trusting employer.

Comment: Honestly that's probably a good call.. I'm still fresh out of college and getting experience so I think I'll stick it out for a bit and then find a better employer when my resume is a little sweeter.

Comment: Did you look at requests-ntlm? https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm

Comment: @schlenk I've tried requests-ntlm, No dice.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by installing Fiddler and using it as my local proxy, while Fiddler itself used the corporate proxy.

Comment: Please share the details of how you did this. I gave it a go and still cannot connect outside the corporate network.Fiddler did work as a proxy for Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I don't remember, tbh. I think it was something like `pip install libname --proxy=http://localhost:12345` where 12345 was the fiddler's port